# how to know the user login fails in python session?

Tags: python, session, python-requests

```
import requests
r=requests.Session()
name="user"
pas="pass123"  
url="http://someurl/login.php"
r.get(url)
```

> Response<200>

```
login_data=dict(username=name,password=pas)
r.post(url,data=login_data)
```

> Response<200>

```
page=r.get("http://someurl/user") #this takes me to the user page
print(page.content)
```

Works fine and takes me to the user's home page.
when i give the wrong user credentials it loads again the same page like facebook etc.the user is not taken to the hoempage.In this case how to know the user has entered is wrong password so I can prompt the user.

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Comment: I've edited.Answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the service you're talking to. For example API endpoints will likely respond with a `40X` status to a failed authentication. On the other hand normal websites are likely to respond with a success and a normal page. In that case you need to figure out if you're logged in either by:

- the url you're redirected to,
- contents of the cookies set by the web app,
- if all else fails - the contents of the website you get back

Comment: thank you.But i suppose depending upon url redirected to and contents are not effecient or doesn't work fine as always means they wont be always same as expected.

Comment: They could change at any time - it is meant for human eyes to see the difference, not necessarily the code. What you could also do is an active check. Attempt to login, then go to a page which you couldn't normally see - if it loads, you're good; if you get redirected to the login page, you're not logged in.